# No sound in Manually Compiled Wine 1.7.18

Tags: 14.04, wine, lubuntu

I downloaded the Wine **1.7.18** source code from Sourceforge, installed the dependencies according to the **./configure** file and compiled & installed (`sudo make && sudo make install`).

The installation was finished successfully. I clicked the audio tab to configure audio, but it says **Selected driver:(None)**. I can't even change the driver. When I click **Test Sound** button, no sound is heard. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of WIne Audio Tab]

The error I got when clicking **Test Sound** button was:

```
err:mmdevapi:DllGetClassObject Driver initialization failed
err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80004005
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
```

How can I fix this sound problem ?

### UPDATE

This same error happened on **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** and **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following commands to get pulseaudio working with wine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will update Wine to a version that supports pulseaudio. Once you have done that, open winecfg and select PulseAudio Driver under Sound Drivers.

Go to [WebUpD8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/install-wine-with-built-in-pulseaudio.html) for a complete tutorial on getting pulseaudio to work with wine.

Comment: The source code I downloaded is of version 1.7.18 and in synaptic when added PPA, it's of the version 1.7.18 too. So aren't both the same ? I won't be able to download 107 MB of files cause my internet connection is slow. This is the reason why I downloaded the 21 MB source code file. If both are same, why need to install with PPA ?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're missing some dependencies.  Another wine user seemed to be having the [same issue](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=15217), and it was suggested they install the `libasound2-dev` package, although they were using Linux Mint, so that may or may not help.

---

The following two methods I found on the Wine Wiki, on [a page](http://wiki.winehq.org/Recommended_Packages) about building Wine, so they might not work for an already-built

The Ubuntu-specific method seems to be to run `sudo apt-get build-dep wine1.5` in a terminal.

However, according to the [Wine Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/Recommended_Packages), the easiest way to install all the correct dependencies is to download and run [this script](http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-wine-deps.sh) as root (e.g. with sudo). (Note: To save the script, either copy paste it into a notepad, or just right-click on the link and click "Save link as".)

Then, in terminal run `sudo sh ./install-wine-deps.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the dependencies. The easiest way is to simply run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine
```

This will install the dependencies required for the repository version of Wine. There may be a time in the future where this is no longer enough but currently speaking, this is enough to build Wine.

As a side-note, watch the output of `./configure`. It will tell you what it thinks is missing and that will give you an opportunity to find the missing library *before* you build (you'll need to `./configure` again after adding the library).

---

I saw you mentioned download size in another comment. The build dependencies for Wine will likely far outstrip a single Wine download (hundreds of megabytes) but you'll only have to download them once. Think about the long term investment before deciding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer makes sense, but I had the same issue ( Debian 3.2.51-1 64 bit, Wine 1.4.1 ) I stacked for a couple of days looking for the solution. But it was pretty simple:

```
sudo apt-get install libwine-alsa
```